# System.Object[] - Export to CSV

Tags: powershell

Could you please  help in correcting the output of below script?

Script :

```
# Computer List
$allComputers = Get-Content '.\path\to\computers.txt'



# get credentials for domain-joined machines and for local machines
$domainCred = Get-Credential -UserName "domain01\admin01" -Message "Please enter the DOMAIN password"
#$localCred  = Get-Credential -UserName "localadmin01" -Message "Please enter the LOCAL password"

# loop through the list of computers and collect output in variable $Results
$Results = foreach($computer in $allComputers) {
    # check if server is pingable before running the query on the server
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {  
        Write-Host "$computer is online!" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black

        $server = Get-ADComputer -Filter "dnshostname -eq '$computer'" -Properties OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if domain joined, use $domainCred, otherwise $localCred
        if ($server) { 
            $cred    = $domainCred
            $version = ([regex]'Windows(?: Server)?[^\w\r\n]+(\w+)').Match($server.OperatingSystem).Groups[1].Value
        } 
        else { 
            $cred    = $localCred
            $info    = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
            $version = ([regex]'Windows(?: Server)?[^\w\r\n]+(\w+)').Match($info.Caption).Groups[1].Value
        }


        if ($version -eq '2016') {



          # Newer OS
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbSession | Select-Object ClientUserName, ClientComputerName }
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName }
        }
        
                elseif ($version -eq '2012') {



          # Newer OS
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbSession | Select-Object ClientUserName, ClientComputerName }
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName }
        }
        
                elseif ($version -eq '2019') {



          # Newer OS
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbSession | Select-Object ClientUserName, ClientComputerName }
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName }
        }
        
                        elseif ($version -eq '10') {



          # Newer OS
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbSession | Select-Object ClientUserName, ClientComputerName }
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName }
        }
}
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $computer is off-line"
        
        [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = 'Off-Line' }
    }

}       

# Output on screen
$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Output to CSV file
$Results | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\smbsession.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Result variable:

```
ComputerName ClientUserName                                                       ClientComputerName                                           
------------ --------------                                                       ------------------                                           
COMPUTER01   {CONTOSO\machine01$, CONTOSO\machine02,...}                          {192.10.12.1, 192.10.12.3,...}
```

My output :

Output :

```
"ComputerName","ClientUserName","ClientComputerName"
"COMPUTER01","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
```

My last output :

```
"ComputerName","ClientUserName","ClientComputerName"
"COMPUTER01","CONTOSO\machine01$;CONTOSO\machine02;  192.10.12.1; 192.10.12.3
```

Comment: `ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName` -->  `ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName -join '; '` and `ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName` --> `ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName -join '; '`

Comment: I have uploaded `my last output` But I can't deliminite correctly inside excel

Comment: You can just change the semi-character `;` I used as example to some other character if that is better for you. Try `-join ' | '`. You can even join by a newline: `-join [environment]::NewLine`. In the final Excel then click Cell properties and tick `Wrap text` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your last output, I think you have done something wrong with the `-join`..

If you replace all parts in the code where you hane

```
  # output an object
  [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName }
```

with

```
  # output an object
  [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; ClientUserName = $SMB.ClientUserName -join '; ' ; ClientComputerName = $SMB.ClientComputerName -join '; ' }
```

You would get

[image]

Or using `-join [Environment]::NewLine`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that ComputerName is just a string, but ClientUserName and ClientComputerName are arrays. Calling .ToString() on an array can return that System.Object[] output.

If ClientUserName and ClientComputerName have the same number of entries and they are correlated in order, and each pair corresponds to the ComputerName in the parent object, I recommend using a for loop from 0 to the array length minus one (inclusive on both ends) and writing one row during each iteration: $ComputerName, $ClientUserName[$i], $ClientComputerName[$i]. Here, $i is the for loop variable and goes from $i = 0 to $i -lt $ClientUserName.Length

That's assuming you want separate rows for entries in the array. If you want one row, just use string join on each array to get one delimited (e.g., space or semicolon or pipe) string.